# CSV Filtering for numpy

Tags: python, list, csv, numpy, filtering

I've got this rather large CSV file, and I only care about the rows that contain the word "Slave"...Some rows that contain Slave are not exactly the same as others, but they all contain the word "Slave".

I want to throw away all the other rows and then work on the data that's left over in the other column.

Here's the catch:  The other column isn't clean either...It always looks like this, though:

`digit (text)`
so, for instance:

`7 (medium)`

`12 (strong)`

I want to grab the first 1 or 2 (depending on if there is 1 or 2 digits, of course) and then plot them in a histogram with numpy and matplotlib/pyplot.

I've got two problems:
This code:

```
import csv
x=csv.reader(open('sample.csv', 'rt'), delimiter=',')
x=list(x)
```

Does OK, but now I have to address things like `x[1][1]`...This will show

```
Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
```

But, something like `x[:][1]` shows

```
['6 (medium)', 'Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)']
```

Which, is not what I expect...I would expect it to just print the second column.

Anyway, if I can get past that, the next issue will be that the surviving column will have some character filtering to do (I guess) to just keep the digits and remove the alpha characters...However, I'm dreading on how to do just that and also be able to stuff in into some numpy friendly data structure.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?  Here's a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
4 (weak),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
4 (weak),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
13 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
10 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
11 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
8 (medium),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
13 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
12 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
10 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
11 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
4 (weak),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
13 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
5 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
11 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
6 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
11 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
13 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
7 (medium),Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)
10 (strong),Master (0x00-25-52-f5-a6-f1) (#1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Wait, why numpy? As a csv, each line contains 2 columns, one before and one after the comma. `x[1][1]` is the second column from the second list, since python uses 0-based indices. And `x[:][1]` is equivalent to `x[1]`, so no surprise there.

Comment: so `Slave (0x00-02-5b-00-a5-a5) (#1)` becomes what?

Comment: I'm willing to abandon numpy...I thought it might pay off when I got to plotting.  I'm still stuck on how to address the filtering of the string 'Slave', at this point.  Can you expand on why the two syntax's are equivalent and where my assumptions are wrong?

Comment: It's row stays in the list....if the tie downs contain "Slave" in that column (the second one), then I want to delete that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a csv, each line contains 2 columns, one before and one after the comma. `x[1][1]` is the second column from the second list, since python uses 0-based indices. And `x[:][1]` is equivalent to `x[1]`, so no surprise there.

I suggest filtering and keeping the very first column that contains your numbers:

```
firstcol_filt = [int(str.split(k[0])[0]) for k in x if 'Slave' in k[1]]
```

then you can transform this list of lists into a numpy array if you wish,

```
firstcol_arr = np.array(firstcol_filt)
```

Due to its shape, this will be a 1d array which you can use in a histogram.

---

Just to elaborate: `x` from your CSV is a list of lists. The list comprehension loops over `x`, `k` is each row of the CSV, so `k` is a two-element list. If `'Slave'` is in the second element, we split the first element at whitespace and transform its first part into an integer.

The list comprehension can be expanded into an equivalent loop like so:

```
firstcol_filt = []
for k in x:
    if 'Slave' in k[1]:
        firstcol_filt.append(int(str.split(k[0])[0]))
```

Since you asked in a comment, here's the filtering step and the splitting step separately, for clarity:

```
filtered_rows = [k for k in x if 'Slave' in k[1]]
firstcol_filt = [int(str.split(k[0])[0]) for k in filtered_rows]
```

Comment: Wow...amazing one liner...So, to make sure I've got this straight, the brackets make `k` special...I noticed it wasn't defined before it was called up with `for`.  Also, why doesn't `int` throw an error for trying to split `k` before it's defined?  And, is it trivial to print the the initial filtering to make sure that only 'Slave' rows were allowed to stay?

Comment: @BrocolliRob the brackets with `k` are called a list comprehension, they are very important tools in python, but in practice they just construct a list in a loop. The list comprehension implicitly defines `k` as it loops over the elements of `x`, so no errors come from there. You can do the filtering step separately, if you wish, to take a look. Please see my update for further explanation, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: That's nice!  I did find something in the many many entries of this data that is causing a problem...I've got some 'N/A' entries where decimal numbers the split statement grabs from.  This is choking `int`.  I've tried this:  `filtered_rows = [k for k in x if 'N/A' not in k[0] or 'Slave' in k[1]] `, but this breaks `firstcol_filt = [int(str.split(k[0])[0]) for k in filtered_rows]
` with a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @BrocolliRob you probably meant `and` in that condition. You probably have lines where there's no `Slave` but there's an N/A, so the syntax of those lines is different and the first block probably doesn't contain whitespace. Even then I'm unsure about how that can lead to that error... So first try it with `and`, because I believe that's what you need. If it breaks still, use a proper `for` loop and find out where the error is coming from (probably using a `try`-`except` block around the splitting step).